# AAPT2 error: check logs for details en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Me encuentro haciendo un proyecto básico en Android Studio en su ultima versión que descargue en Mayo del 2018, cuando intento compilar el proyecto me aparece el clásico error de "AAPT2 error: check logs for details" lo cual toda la clase Main me marca errores en las letras R.layout.
Ahora bien buscando en otros foros encontré que para evitar este error tenemos que regresar a una versión de drivers antigua con la instrucción  android.enableAapt2=false en gradle.properties y dándole en Sync Now para compilarla lo cual ya intente pensando que se solucionaría mi problema y me arroja lo siguiente:

> The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used
>   anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning. It
>   will be removed at the end of 2018..

Necesito ayuda por favor ya que esto me lo hace en cada proyecto que creo.

```
package com.example.obed.mycalculadorafinal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText num1, num2;
    Button suma , resta , mult, divi;
    TextView resultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
        num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);

        suma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sumar);
        resta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restar);
        mult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplicar);
        divi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dividir);

        resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);


        suma.setOnClickListener(this);
        resta.setOnClickListener(this);
        mult.setOnClickListener(this);
        divi.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String n1 = num1.getText().toString();
        String n2 = num2.getText().toString();

        int entero1=Integer.parseInt(n1);
        int entero2=Integer.parseInt(n2);

        int rta=0;

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.sumar:
                rta=entero1+entero2;
                break;
            case R.id.restar:
                rta=entero1-entero2;
                break;
            case R.id.multiplicar:
                rta=entero1*entero2;
                break;
            case R.id.dividir:
                rta=entero1/entero2;
                break;
        }

        resultado.setText(""+rta);
    }
}
```

---

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<EditText
    android:ide="@+id/num1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imputType="number"
    android:hint="número 1"
    />
<EditText
    android:ide="@+id/num2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imputType="number"
    android:hint="número 2"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sumar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Sumar"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/restar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Restar"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/multiplicar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Multi"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dividir"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Dividir"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultado"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="120sp"/>
```

Comment: Realiza el cambio que comento en el archivogradle.properties  @SuriGang'sHallen saludos.

Answer (score -1):

En realidad puedes tener problemas en los recursos pero estos no se van a visualizar si no corriges primero el error:

> The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used
>   anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning. It
>   will be removed at the end of 2018.

para esto, dentro de tu archivo `gradle.properties` que se encuentra en la raíz del proyecto reemplaza:

```
android.enableAapt2
```

por:

```
android.enableAapt2=true
```

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.